# Executing multiple requests elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am executing the following requests in elastic search through Chrome sense plugin:

```
    DELETE /state
    PUT /state
    PUT /state/mapping/_mapping
    {
        "state" : {
            "index_analyzer" : "angram",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard", 
            "properties" : {
                "stateName": {

                       "type" : "multi_field",
                       "fields": {
                        "stateName":{
                               "type":"string"
                       },
                    "untouched":{
                    "type" : "string","index" :"not_analyzed"
                       }

                    }
            },
                "countryName": 
                {

                       "type" : "multi_field",
                       "fields": {
                        "countryName":{
                               "type":"string"
                       },
                    "untouched":{
                    "type" : "string","index" :"not_analyzed"
                       }

                    }
            }

            }
        }
    }

    DELETE /_river/state
    PUT /_river/state/_meta
    { 
        "type": "mongodb", 
        "mongodb": { 
            "db": "rakeshdb", 
            "collection": "state"
        }, 
        "index": {
            "name": "state", 
            "type": "mapping" 


   }
}
```

I have to execute each DELETE and PUT request separately. Is there anyway to execute the complete script in a single shot.

Comment: Could you please let me know whether the answer you got was useful?

Answer (score 0):

No, the only thing you can do is merge the index creation with the put mapping call into a single create index call that contains the mappings too.

But you cannot delete an index and create one (even if another one) on the same request.